# 220V current measurement?

Tags: circuit-design, ac, current-measurement

I want to design an current protection circuit with current sense amplifier. I have to work with 220V 50Hz AC bus voltage. I could not find any IC or any design for this topic. Can someone give me some hints about this?
*I just find IC that ACS709 but I could not be sure whether it is okay or not.

Comment: Start with specifications. [Edit] your question to specify: (1) What current range you are using. (2) What the trip point will be. (3) What the trip time will be. (4) What you are going to do when overcurrent is detected. (5) Are you going to limit the current or disconnect the supply. (6) Solid-state solution or relay. (7) Why will an MCB not do the job? When you've done that you'll be in a position to start selecting a suitable monitoring circuit and switch.

Comment: Are you familiar with working in such high-voltage environments? This is an application that does not allow for mistakes.

Comment: I expect you would choose a range of current peak that is near 41% above RMS rating of your branch or breaker current rating and interface to 3.3V logic device. Such as +/-35A for a 20A breaker which operates linear up to 70A. This looks like a good solution. Or choose the 5A one for smaller loads. You decide.

Comment: I do not have experience but I do not implement project in reality. I just have to find an IC that I can use. Mains voltage is 220V and I will sense current up to 16A and I will cut off the current when overcurrent detected. I just need an IC that can work with mains voltage or if I have a IC that can sense up to 16A then for example its supply voltage is 20V. Is it okay or not?

Comment: Why connect an IC to the mains?  Is there a reason you can't use a current transformer?

Comment: Are you familiar with CT transformers? You can use to detect and measure current. I think it's one of your cheapest and safest way, all you have to do is pass the wire that you want measure it's current, through the CT transformer and measure CT's voltage that is a low voltage and safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I just find IC that ACS709 but I could not be sure whether it is okay
> or not*

The ACS709 is fine for power AC mains applications. It's not so good for high speed SMPS current monitoring because it only has a bandwidth of 120 kHz (unlike the ACS730 series which is good for up to 1 MHz).

The main useful feature in either model is that the input current sensing is galvanically isolated from the analogue output interface and this means you don't need a transformer to provide electrical protection but, it's still connected to mains AC so care must be taken when laying out the PCB to ensure creepage and clearance distances are maintained.

However, both devices are somewhat ambiguous on their isolation capacitance so don't expect perfect behaviour if your line voltage is quite noisy. This particularly applies to measuring current in SMPS circuits if your measurement point is on a high-speed switching node - you will get significant cross talk that can spoil an otherwise nice rendition of the current signal you are trying to measure.

Make sure you choose one that is suitable for the current peaks you are trying to monitor because significant over-range can cause oddball effects on the device that are hard to debug/understand.

Comment: the ACS790 data sheet say this part is good up-to 277VAC so yes it's fine at 220V https://www.pololu.com/file/0J498/ACS709.pdf  bottom of page 2.  This is basic isolation, so the low-voltage part needs to be grounded (or additionally isolated) for safety.